# Resource constraints in iOS simulator vs OS X

Tags: macos, resources, ios-simulator

I've written a search algorithm for a puzzle game in Objective-C. Initially I envisioned this algorithm running in an iOS app hence I've been testing it mainly using the iOS simulator. Now it's become apparent that it isn't restricted to running in the app. So it can just run on OS X. Since the search algorithm is fairly resource intensive (it solves a complex puzzle using BFS) I'm wondering about resource constraints.

**What resource constraints does the iOS simulator impose in terms of memory usage and CPU?**

Once I understand these constraints I can make a better decision regarding running the algorithm just from the terminal and possibly porting it to another language.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS simulator doesn't impose any constraints on memory or CPU usage. If you pull your code out into a native application then it should run identically.